# Can you provide me with advice for choosing appropriate materials for rebuilding the roof over my dug well?

Tags: roof, well, materials

My water supply is an 18' dug well with 24" inside diameter. The top of the well casing is below grade and within a 4' x 8' block foundation, about 3'6" deep. The well, pump and pressure tank are all enclosed in this area. The head of the well casing is enclosed with tight fitting, unfinished 2 x 6 spruce boards with a removable inspection piece.  All is covered with an 80+ year old A-frame roof covered in asphalt shingles. This roof has rotted away and is infested with carpenter ants. The roof had only a thin layer of Homasote for insulation. I wish to rebuild the roof as well as insulate it. My concerns are toxicity of the framing and sheathing if I were to use pressure treated material in order to discourage the carpenter ants . My plan was to use a 2" foil faced insulation between the rafters, an ice and water shield over the sheathing and finish with new asphalt shingles. I am also concerned about ventilation.

Comment: I have worked in the Pacific Northwest for over 30 years and if I wanted to prevent carpenter ants Or termites from being a problem without chemicals I go metal frame and tin siding or roofing, the problem I can see here is the ants will go below grade and eat your cap since it is wood (if I read that right) a metal frame , as far as insulation stay away from foam foil faced or not they love it and you will soon find foam dust everywhere outside. But foil faced fiberglass ants won’t bother, cover the area with diatomaceous earth, it is used to increase filter efficiency in some pool filters.

Comment: "My concerns are toxicity of the framing and sheathing" in terms of what? You probably want it to be toxic to the ants, right? That'll keep them from eating it or kill 'em if they try. Are you worried about it effecting your water supply? Is there some other concern? Please [edit] your question because what you're worried about is rather vague.